# Having issues with a replace function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Okay, so I have some variables in javascript...

```
var link = 'http://8wayrun.com/streams/multi?type=3&pos1=1.teamsp00ky.video&pos2=1.teamsp00ky.chat&pos3=1.nycfurby.chat';
var position = 2;
```

As you can see, I have a link and a position. Using the position var I would like to replace some text in the link field. I would like to strip `&pos2=1.teamsp00ky.chat` from the link. Naturally, I have to do some basic regular expressions; the problem comes into when I try to use the position var in the regex. I just can't figure it out.

In PHP I could do the following:

```
preg_replace('/&pos'.$position.'=[^&]*/i', '', $link);
```

I tried the following in JS, but its not working:

```
link.replace(new RegExp('&pos'+position+'=[^&]*'), '');
```

Could someone help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Also, how would I make it case-insensitive?

Comment: In fact, in PHP `preg_replace` doesn't modify `$link` either. You still have to do the assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the value, not just call the method:

```
link = link.replace(new RegExp('&pos'+position+'=[^&]*'), '');
```

To make it case insensitive, use this regex:

```
new RegExp('&pos'+position+'=[^&]*', "i")
```

Although it *might* make it easier if you split the string on the "?", then split up the key/value pairs by "&", and then split them by "=".

Comment: @JasonAxelrod Haha no problem, it's just different in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) does not mutate the string, but returns a new one - you'd have to assign it somewhere.

> Also, how would I make it case-insensitive?

Pass the `i` flag to the [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```
link = link.replace(new RegExp('&pos'+position+'=[^&]*', 'i'), '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="result"></div>

var link = 'http://8wayrun.com/streams/multi?type=3&pos1=1.teamsp00ky.video&pos2=1.teamsp00ky.chat&pos3=1.nycfurby.chat';
var position = 2;

var start = link.indexOf("pos2");

var end = link.indexOf("&", start);

document.getElementById("result").textContent = link.slice(0, start) + link.slice(end + 1);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/JhS2Q/)